# Referencing Table Column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search through a specific column within a table. I had the code functions when i look the entire sheet column with

```
Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Range("B:B")
```

I tried two different ways of referencing the table's column, but either function

```
Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Range(Table2[Código do Imóvel])
Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows(1)
Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1)
```

Someone know how to reference only to the table column in VBA?

Below is the pieces of code that includes the problem

```
'Worked
If Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value <> Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value Then
        Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3"), Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Range("B:B"), 0), 2).Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
        Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
    End If

'Dont work
If Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value <> Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value Then
        Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3"), Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows(1), 0), 2).Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
        Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
    End If

'Dont work
If Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value <> Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value Then
        Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3"), Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Range("Table2[Código do Imóvel]"), 0), 2).Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
        Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
    End If

'Dont work
If Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value <> Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value Then
        Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3"), Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1), 0), 2).Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
        Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("I3").Value
    End If
```

Edit: included the
Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1)
It returned a type mismatch error

Answer (score 1):

Use ListColumns:

```
Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(1)
```

Comment: Open the Watch Window(Alt V+H). Highlight and drag the different sections of the line to the watch window until you find the one with the mismatch error.

Comment: Sheets("Tabela de Imóveis").Cells(Application.Match(Sheets("Alterar Registro de Imóveis").Range("F3"), Worksheets("Tabela de Imóveis").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns("Código do Imóvel"), 0), 2).Value returns the mismatch error. The expression for the table column's seems to work just fine. I'm trying to give a new value to a specific cell within the table, tried the .Cells(Match, column's number) but it returns this error. Some ideia? Thanks for the help